# Configuring Apache vhost: sites having inner sites. possible?

Tags: apache

i am wondering if i am doing some thing wrong

i have `http://localhost` pointing to the directory `D:\Projects\Websites`

then i want to create a inner site `http://learningzf` in `D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\public`. this is so that i can use URL's like `/users/login` instead of specifying the full url

i find that if i add the entry in `vhosts` to point `http://learningzf` to `D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\public`, localhost will also point to `D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\public`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Websites/php/ZendFramework/LearningZF/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "D:/Projects/Websites/php/ZendFramework/LearningZF/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Websites"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "D:/Projects/Websites">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

i noticed if i move the entries for `learningzf` below `localhost`, both `learningzf` &`localhost` will point to `D:/Projects/Websites`

**UPDATE**

following [@KikoV answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266218/configuring-apache-vhost-sites-having-inner-sites-possible/3266508#3266508), i have modified it to make it work ...

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Websites"
  <Directory "D:/Projects/Websites">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost learningzf:80>
  ServerName learningzf
  DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Websites/php/ZendFramework/LearningZF/public"
  <Directory "D:/Projects/Websites/php/ZendFramework/LearningZF/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NameVirtualHost directive.
If host "learningzf" is pointing to localhost,  (127.0.0.1), you could use:

Note: In _default _ , last underscore should go togheter.

```
   NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

     <VirtualHost _default _:80>
       ServerName localhost
        <Directory "D:/Projects/Websites">
          AllowOverride All
          Options All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost learningzf:80>
       ServerName learningzf
        <Directory D:/Projects/Websites/php/ZendFramework/LearningZF/public">
          AllowOverride All
          Options All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

This way you could access to http://localhost and http://learningzf and Apache will know which should use.
(By default, it will go to D:/Projects/Websites).

Note2: remember to add "127.0.0.1 learningzf" line to c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file in order to get hostname resolved.

Comment: it seems now, `http://localhost` is going to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs`... so i made afew changes ... add `DirectoryRoot` and then `http://learningzf` works. `http://localhost` points to apache htdocs. so i changed `_default_` to `localhost`. full code posted in update in post

Comment: yup!, I forgot the DocumentRoot... sorry,